# Can't use custom width with Angular-Slick

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Has anybody worked with [Angular-Slick](https://github.com/vasyabigi/angular-slick)?  I'm trying to use this directive so I can get a carousel that displays multiple images/cards.  Everything works fine but I can't get to customize the CSS width of the images.  I set the `variableWidth` to true, but nothing.  I also removed the `slides-to-show` option so variableWidth can work, but no results — I still get the default width by Slick.  Here is the code below:

```
<slick infinite="true" slides-to-show="4" slides-to-scroll="4"
       init-onload="true" data="popularCourses" variableWidth="true" arrows="true">
  <div class="homepage-course-box" ui-sref="courses.show({id: popCourse.id})" ng-repeat="popCourse in popularCourses">
    <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
      <div class="course-img"
           ui-sref="courses.show({id: popCourse.id})"
           ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{popCourse.banner_url}})'}"></div>
      <div class="author-avatar" ng-style="{'background-image':'url({{popCourse.author.avatar}})'}"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" style="margin:0;">
      <a ui-sref="courses.show({id: popCourse.id})" class="homepage-course-title">{{popCourse.title}}</a>
    </div>
    <div class="row homepage-course-last-row">
      <p class="author-name">{{popCourse.author.full_name}}</p>
      <p class="course-duration">{{popCourse.duration | secondsToHHMM | date: "H'H' mm'M'"}}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
</slick>
```

From the code, I'm using `ng-repeat` so it displays all the images, I'm suspecting is interfering with the width, I may be wrong.

So far I like this angular directive, but it will be awesome if I can set my own custom CSS width.  Please can anybody help with this!  Your help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Html is not case sensitive so angular requires dashes in attribute names on directives. So instead of `variableWidth` put `variable-width`.